# Boolean tool useless for removing an end piece

Tags: modifiers

Been stuck on this for a day now, cannot remove the end circle that is protruding out. Boolean tool doesn't do it. Neither does it work in edit mode. Why does it have to be so complicated?

[image: Trying to remove the end piece but boolean tool doesn't work]

Comment: Could you upload your file using this link? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. Also, what do you want to do: flattening this part along the cylinder or totally remove it?

Comment: Please do not ask the same question over again.

Answer (score 0):

Make a loop cut at the center and delete the half with the extra edge made on the right hand (as per the question)
Click on the center vertex and Press Shit+S > cursor to selected in object mode press ctrl+Shift+Alt+C and select origin to 3d cursor . And then add mirror modifier on z axis
[image]